# C# Trying to use a method to assign attributes of an old object to new objects

Tags: c#, class, object, methods, attributes

I'm new to c# and programing in general, like a few weeks, and this has stumped me. The code below is the one I'm having trouble with.

```
internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Students tester1 = new Students();
            Students tester2 = new Students();

            Assigner(tester1, tester2);

            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}.",
                tester1.name, tester2.name);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}.",
                tester1.birthday, tester2.birthday);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}.",
                tester1.height, tester2.height);


            Console.ReadLine();
        }


       public static void Assigner(Students aMulti1, Students aMulti2)
        {
            Students student1 = new Students("Jack", 0411, 155);
            Students student2 = new Students("Kelly", 0704, 179);
            Students student3 = new Students("Gabriel", 1212, 177);
            Students student4 = new Students("Irene", 0222, 169);
            Students student5 = new Students("Anderson", 0115, 162);

            Shuffler shuffler = new Shuffler();
            List<Students> studentList = new List<Students> 
            { student1, student2, student3, student4, student5 };
            shuffler.Shuffle(studentList);

            aMulti1 = studentList[0];
            aMulti2 = studentList[1];

        }
```

My intention was to randomize a list (studentList) of objects then have the input object take on the attributes of a randomly chosen object from the list. The problem is that the method does not seem to do anything as tester1 and tester2 still have empty attributes.

The class codes are below, with me having copied the Shuffler.

```
    public class Shuffler
    {
        public Shuffler()
        {
            _rng = new Random();
        }

        public void Shuffle<T>(IList<T> array)
        {
            for (int n = array.Count; n > 1;)
            {
                int k = _rng.Next(n);
                --n;
                T temp = array[n];
                array[n] = array[k];
                array[k] = temp;
            }
        }

        private System.Random _rng;
    }

    public class Students
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int birthday { get; set; }
        public int height { get; set; }

        public Students()
        {

        }

        public Students (string aName, int aBirthday, int aHeight)
        {
            name = aName;
            birthday = aBirthday;
            height = aHeight;
        }

    }
```

I've tested the method itself below and it works, having tester1 and tester2 take on the attributes of the random students.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Students tester1 = new Students();
            Students tester2 = new Students();

            Students student1 = new Students("Jack", 0411, 155);
            Students student2 = new Students("Kelly", 0704, 179);
            Students student3 = new Students("Gabriel", 1212, 177);
            Students student4 = new Students("Irene", 0222, 169);
            Students student5 = new Students("Anderson", 0115, 162);

            Shuffler shuffler = new Shuffler();
            List<Students> studentList = new List<Students> { student1, student2, student3, student4, student5 };
            shuffler.Shuffle(studentList);

            tester1 = studentList[0];
            tester2 = studentList[1];

            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}.", 
                tester1.name, tester2.name);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}.",
                tester1.birthday, tester2.birthday);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}.",
                tester1.height, tester2.height);

            Console.ReadLine();


        }
```

What is giving me a pause, is that the original method I've written, but way bulkier and unnecessarily messy and what I've been trying to rework, seemed to work, but it required me to generate and randomize a list of string first and then use the string as an if condition to determine which attributes are assigned.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Students tester1 = new Students();
            Students tester2 = new Students();

            Shuffler shuffler = new Shuffler();
            List<string> studentList = new List<string> {
                   "student1", "student2", "student3", "student4", "student5"};
            shuffler.Shuffle(studentList);

            tester1.name = studentList[0];
            tester2.name = studentList[1];

            Assigner(tester1);
            Assigner(tester2);

            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}.",
                tester1.name, tester2.name);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}.",
                tester1.birthday, tester2.birthday);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}.",
                tester1.height, tester2.height);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void Assigner(Students choice)
        {
            Students student1 = new Students("Jack", 0411, 155);
            Students student2 = new Students("Kelly", 0704, 179);
            Students student3 = new Students("Gabriel", 1212, 177);
            Students student4 = new Students("Irene", 0222, 169);
            Students student5 = new Students("Anderson", 0115, 162);

            if (choice.name == "student1")
            {
                choice.name = student1.name;
                choice.birthday = student1.birthday;
                choice.height = student1.height;
            }

            else if (choice.name == "student2")
            {
                choice.name = student2.name;
                choice.birthday = student2.birthday;
                choice.height = student2.height;
            }

            else if (choice.name == "student3")
            {
                choice.name = student3.name;
                choice.birthday = student3.birthday;
                choice.height = student3.height;
            }

            else if (choice.name == "student4")
            {
                choice.name = student4.name;
                choice.birthday = student4.birthday;
                choice.height = student4.height;
            }

            else if (choice.name == "student5")
            {
                choice.name = student5.name;
                choice.birthday = student5.birthday;
                choice.height = student5.height;
            }


        }
```

I going to guess that this is because the Shuffler method happened inside another method that it didn't work, since the ones that did work had the shuffling done outside of the method, but I have no idea where to go next. I want to make my code look a bit better and to make it easier to maintain. If I go with the working method, I have to add so many ifs conditions instead of just having to enter the object and attribute once.

Is there anything I can do here, or is my approach itself wrong? I'm ready and eager to learn. Thank you.

Comment: It isn't the problem, but `Students` should be called `Student`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, `Assigner` cannot modify the variables in `Main`. You need to use `out` parameters for that to be possible:

```
public static void Assigner(out Students aMulti1, out Students aMulti2)
```

And you must also specify that in the call to `Assigner`:

```
        Assigner(out tester1, out tester2);
```

Since the original values of `tester1` and `tester2` are simply going to be overwritten, there is no point to assign them to student objects, but you still need to declare them:

```
        Students tester1;
        Students tester2;
```

It really doesn't make sense to call the class `Students` when each instance represents one student, but I have left the name unchanged here.

Comment: I modified the code with your suggests and it worked. Thanks you. Is there any further reading I can look into to better understand  it, because the "out" never came up in the video I watched. I also wanted to ask is it possible for me to do that method in a separate class, and is there a reason why the code in my fourth code block example worked?

Comment: @kenLeeDep You could read the documentation on the [out parameter modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier), for one. The reason your fourth code block worked is because it is *modifying* the `tester1` and `tester2` objects, instead of trying to assign to them.

Comment: By the way, you can accept my answer by clicking the checkmark, if you want.

Comment: Got it. Still new to the site. Thank you, and for the follow up answers as well.